# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'WholeFileReader'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, filereader, attributeerror

I have been trying to implement this piece of code and realized a lot has been deprecated and updated in TensorFlow V2.
**CODE**

```
filenames=['images/000001.jpg','images/000002.jpg','images/000003.jpg','images/000004.jpg']
labels=[1,0,1,0]

filename_queue=tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

reader=tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
images=tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)
images=tf.cast(images, tf.float32)
resized_images=tf.image.resize_images(images, (224, 224))
```

I have altered the `tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)` part. But I am not able to find any alternative to `tf.WholeFileReader()`. Also I am using google colab and thus cannot  rely on V1 as it says colab don't support TensorFlow V2.
Here's my piece of code.

**My code**

```
import os
import numpy as np
image_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive'
categ = ["IMG"]

for c in categ:
  path = os.path.join(image_path, c)
  for img in os.listdir(path):
    image = [os.path.join(path, img)]
    
    
queue=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image)
reader=tf.WholeFileReader() #AttributeError
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be able to find it here:

```
tf.io.WholeFileReader()
```

instead of

```
tf.WholeFileReader()
```

Comment: Hi, @Finn. I am sorry to say it didn't work for me. Though this thread `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.10.0/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py#L430-L455` helped me. Yet, couldn't perform the read operation to distinguish the filename and content. Later I used, based on the link provided..... `from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_io_ops` and then.... `gen_io_ops.whole_file_reader_v2()`